# Button template with image and text in wpf

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, custom-controls

I want to create buttons with images and text inside. For example, i would use different images and text for buttons like 'Browse folders' and 'Import'.

One of the options would be to use a template. I had a look at similar question

[Creating an image+text button with a control template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933127/creating-an-imagetext-button-with-a-control-template)

But is there any way by which I can bind the source of image without using a dependency property or any other class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. What would you bind the `Image.Source` to? You need a DependencyProperty for this. Of course, you could also define a normal class which contains two properties: `Text` and `ImageSource` or `Uri`, and then use a DataTemplate to render instances of this class, but that would be even more code to write, and it is a little "smelly".

What is the reason you do not want to use a dependency property or a custom class?

Comment: The only reason is i wanted to know if there is any other simple way or you can say rather 'less-code' way to do it. With texblock i can use <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" /> I wanted to know why cant i do the same with the Source property of an Image?

Comment: But **where** would you put that `TemplateBinding`? And to **which property** would you bind?

Comment: Can I use 'Tag' property to bind it?

Comment: I am not sure. It might work. However, personally, I would consider this as pretty bad code because the intention is not clear, you do not have any type-safety... It is up to you.

Answer (score 66):

It doesn't have to be that complicated. Something as simple as putting a StackPanel inside a button will do the trick:

```
<Button>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>My text here</TextBlock>
    <Image Source="some.jpg" Stretch="None" />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Then you can configure the StackPanel to control where the text should appear, alignment, etc.

Comment: Okay, but how do you set the underline character?  If I put "_My text here" it renders the underline and alt+M no longer works.  So how do you get that back?

Comment: Also, how do you get it to shrink the image so that the button doesn't explode to the size of your image (i.e. if I have an image that's 40x40 and a button of whatever size buttons are -- I don't want to manually set that -- how do I get the image to shrink to the right size instead of blow up my button to be uber large?

Comment: I'd like to add that you'll probably want to set the `Orientation` of the `StackPanel` to `Horizontal` to get them to line up side by side. Note that if you used a grid instead of a StackPanel you'd have to play with margins to center the image and text on the button horizontally (So the stackpanel is the way to go).

Comment: THIS is the answer

Comment: Now image and text are centered inside the button. How can I left-align them?

Comment: a lot of long Codes to answers this on the internet , but you brought simple short idea that no one thought of lol , gg wp

Answer (score 18):

I added a few things to line them up nicely

```
<Button>
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Image Source="/ApplicationName;component/Images/MyImage.ico"/>
       <Label Padding="0">My Button Text</Label>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Well that worked to give me a normal button label (i.e. with alt+letter hot keys) -- I tested it clicks the button when I press the correct combination. -- Now I just need to figure out how to shrink my image to the size of the button and to not cause it to make the buttons all huge.

Comment: How can i stretch StackPanel inside the Button? `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` does not work. P.S. WPF is unpredictable and stupid.

Answer (score 7):

```
    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="Resources/add.png" Stretch="None" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">Add</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<Button x:Name="MyCoolButton"Width="200" Height="75">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="Pete-Brown-Silverlight-in-Action.png" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="Buy My Book!" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text="Pete is writing THE Silverlight 4 book" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Added **Stretch="Uniform"** to Sean's answer to address case if the image is originally larger than the button size (issue BrainSlugs83 mentioned in his comments that I ran into as well). More details of Stretch options at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="/ApplicationName;component/Images/MyImage.ico" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <Label Padding="0">My Button Text</Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Wanted to add this as a comment to the answer under BrainSlugs83 but can't yet due to lack of points and was rejected from editing Sean's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the [IconButton](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/IconButton) of the XCeed WPF Toolkit (freeware) does the trick.