# show the content and the background in a button 

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to show in a button a text and an image (i mean one at the top and the other at the bottom of the button, so both can be well visible) so i put the image as background and the text as the content of the button, but it puts both at the same space so they look mixed, how can i separate the content and the background?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Grid in a control template? Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726986/button-template-with-image-and-text-in-wpf

Answer (score 3):

A `Button` can hold any content. In this case, create a `StackPanel` in the Button and add the content:

```
<Button>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock />
    <Image />
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```