# How can I get the 'default button appearance' in a CustomControl derived from Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, custom-controls

Just tried out to write an own custom control for a button with the help of [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933127/creating-an-imagetext-button-with-a-control-template)

But the Button control is **empty** besides the image and the text.

Is there any possibility to use default behavior if nothing else is specified?

I do not want to re-write a whole button, if already an almost suiting exists. Just wanted to add an ImageSource and a text and some, not all, styling.

Here is what I've got, perhaps I just made some mistake.

Class definition:

```
public class MyImageButton : Button
{
    static MyImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyImageButton)));
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

From the generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyImageButton}">
                <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And finally the usage in the mainwindow xaml

```
<ctrl:MyImageButton ImageSource="SomeImage.png" Text="BlaBlubb" Height="100" Width="120" Click="CheckClick" />
```

Comment: `Is there any possibility to use default behavior if nothing else is specified?` - I don't understand. If you inherit from `Button` you `already have` the behavior from `Button`. Did you mean appearance? these are 2 completely different (and separate) concepts in WPF.

Comment: What I want is a button, not an image and a text. This seems to be destroyed here. I get two elements on the mainwindow, but nothing that looks close to a button

Comment: That's because your ControlTemplate is specifying just what you are seeing - a StackPanel with an Image and a TextBlock. The ControlTemplate of a button is actually much more complex. See [this page](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/wpf-kid-stuff-extracting) to find out how to extract the ControlTemplate of a button, or [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a Button ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
But the Button control is empty besides the image and the text.
```

That is what you have implemented here:

```
<StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
</StackPanel>
```

What do you mean by default behavior?

An easy option would be to do this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyImageButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyImageButton}">
                <Button>
                    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding ImageSource}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Second option, probably best in your case:

Derive a UserControl from button, about like this:

```
<Button x:class="..."
        x:Name="root">
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Image, ElementName=root}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

and define the dependency properties in the codebehind of the UserControl.

As a rule of thumb: Use UserControls, when your goal is to arrange (other) controls in a reusable way.

Comment: This is definitly what I want! Thank you very much! And thanks for the hint!