# Styling a WPF Button with Image+Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, .net-4.5

In my C#/WPF/.NET 4.5 application I have buttons with images that I implemented in the following fashion:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BigButton}">
  <StackPanel>
    <Image Source="Images/Buttons/bt_big_save.png" />
    <TextBlock>save</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I have a resource dictionary **UIStyles.xaml** in which I declare the following:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BigButton">
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="border" 
            CornerRadius="5" 
            Background="#FF415360">
          <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"  
              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
              </Style>
              <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
              </Style>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
          </ContentPresenter>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The cursor, height, border etc. properties work fine, but I can't style the `TextBlock` and the `Image`.

Specifically, what needs to look like this:

[image: correct look]

Ends up looking like this (disregarding the color difference):

[image: incorrect look]

I've seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933127/creating-an-imagetext-button-with-a-control-template) asked before but the solutions used different approaches (I don't want to create a custom User Control, all of my needs except this one are covered in the present code and re-writing will be a nuisance). I merely need to fix my `Style` so that the `TextBlock` is centered and the `Image` is centered and made smaller.

How do I re-write the `Style` to correct the look of my buttons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to your problem may be to move your Image and TextBlock styles to the ControlTemplate's Resource section. I'm not sure *why*, but I believe the styles aren't in scope if they are part of the content presenter's resources.

Comment: This is correct, the styles in the `<ContentPresenter.Resources>` are not getting applied. Moving them to `<ControlTemplate.Resources>` makes the UI look as expected.

Answer (score 11):

Try something like this:

The `Button`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BigButton}" Content="save">
    <Button.Tag>
        <ImageSource>../GreenLamp.png</ImageSource>
    </Button.Tag>
</Button>
```

The `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BigButton">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="#FF415360">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Height="50"
                                Margin="5" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You might have to change the `Height`/`Margin` for the `Image` in the `Style` to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it will work if you set Button's ContentTemplate instead of Content.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource BigButton}">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="Resources/icon_cancel.png" />
            <TextBlock>save</TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use height property to fix Image height to let say 30(depend on your reqirement)  and use HorzontalAllignment to center for textblock It wil work fine

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.