# How to change image on mouseover on a button with stackpanel having an Image and a Textblock XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm kinda new to WPF/XAML

I have this Button that holds a stack panel which is having an Image and a Textbox Control to it.

I have styled the button in a StaticResource

How can I achieve an image change on MouseOver?

I have accomplished changing the Background color, and the Foreground color (text) to change on mouseover, but I can't get the image change to work

This is my Button:

```
                <Button Style="{StaticResource mainMenuHomeBtn}">
                    <StackPanel
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Name="hjemImage" Margin="5" Height="30" Source="/Images/fal-home-lg-alt.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Hjem"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
```

And this is my Button Styling:

```
        <Style x:Key="mainMenuHomeBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e3e3e3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#cccccc" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#696969"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d9d9d9"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e3e3e3"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: In order to implement an "image change" in a Button Style, the Style would have to declare a Template that contains an Image element, instead of just a ContentPresenter. Perhaps move the StackPanel with the Image into the ControlTemplate and use a ContentPresenter instead of the TextBlock.

Comment: Can you give an example, as i'm new to XAML and WPF? =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1933156/1136211 There is plenty of similar stuff here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Didn't have any luck with that. 
I'll just go with the next best thing. Just slightly tint my mouseover background, so i can use the same picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Style`/`ControlTemplate` doesn't know anything about the `StackPanel` that happens to be in the element that is currently set as the `Content` of the `Button` element that the `Style` is currently applied to.

You could move the contents to the template and use a trigger so change the `Source` of the `Image` element in the template:

```
<Style x:Key="mainMenuHomeBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-2"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e3e3e3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#cccccc" BorderThickness="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Image Name="hjemImage" Margin="5" Height="30" Source="/Images/fal-home-lg-alt.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Hjem"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="hjemImage" Property="Source" Value="pic.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#696969"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#d9d9d9"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e3e3e3"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then there is no point of setting the `Content` property since there is no `ContentPresenter` in the `Style`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource mainMenuHomeBtn}" />
```

The other option is to keep your `Style` as-is and add a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `IsMouseOver` property of the `Button` to an element in the content:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource mainMenuHomeBtn}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Image Name="hjemImage" Margin="5" Height="30">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/fal-home-lg-alt.png" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pic.png" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <TextBlock Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Hjem"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I chose the last of your options where you define the Datatrigger for the button it self, as I have more than just the homebutton, with different pictures and texts.
It works like a charm.